# R baseplot :plotting 2 density plots in 1 plot cand hanging scales for x-Axis and y-Axis

Tags: r, plot, scale, radix, density-plot

I have a question concerning plots in R using the baseplot-system:
I want to plot 2 density plots in 1 plot. For this they need to have the same scales. I managed to change the scales so that I can plot them into 2 different plots. Thats exactly how I want them to look like:

```
 mexp = NULL
 for (i in 1 : 1000) mexp = c(mexp, mean(rexp(1000, 0.2)))
 hist(mexp, col="lightblue", main = "Averages of 40 exponentials")

plot(density(rnorm(1000,mean= 5)), bw=11,col="red" )
plot(   density( mexp , frequency(F)  ), col="green")  # frequency(F) adjusts the y-Axis
```

When I try to plot them into 1 plot it doesn`t work: I see the first plot only. I did this:

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000,mean= 5)), bw=11,col="red" )
line(   density( mexp , frequency(F) , col="green" ))
```

Can anybody help me ? Thank you!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.  It would be helpful to include which library you used for `mexp` but more to the point,  what is F?  we cannot run your code.

Comment: when I use frequency(F) the y-Axis is normalized. I don`t know what F is

Comment: could you type `str(F)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is better, but still contains several nonsense items.

First of all,  it looks like you are comparing the wrong distributions. Your mexp data looks plausible.  However,  it looks like you are trying to compare it to a normal distribution with mean=5 and standard deviation=1. The mean is very close to the mean of your mexp data, but the mexp data has a mean of 0.157. You will not get much of  a match like that.

Next the code has some mistakes and some absolute rubbish. Your first plot is:

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000,mean= 5)), bw=11,col="red" )
```

Aside from the fact that you have an inappropriate standard deviation for the normal distribution, you have bw=11 as an argument for `plot`, which no such argument. `bw` is an argument for `density` but this is probably not a good choice for bw on this data. Let's just plot it using the default choice of `bw` and adjust that later if needed. So a better version of your first curve would be:

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000,mean=5, sd=sd(mexp)), ),col="red" )
```

Next, you have

```
line(   density( mexp , frequency(F) , col="green" ))
```

There *is* a function `line`, but that is not what you want here. You are looking for `lines`. With `lines` you are plotting another density. The argument `col="green"` is misplaced. You have it as an argument to `density` when it should be an argument for `lines`. And then there is `frequency(F)`.  This is gibberish. Here F will be treated as the logical value FALSE. `frequency` will consider that as a time series and find the frequency so that will give the value 1.  You are then supplying that as the second argument of `density` so it will be treated as a bandwidth.  This is total nonsense. Let's just delete it. That leaves us with `lines(density(mexp), col="green")` Putting this all together, we get:

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000,mean=5, sd=sd(mexp)), ),col="red" )
lines(density(mexp) , col="green" )
```

[image: Two densities]

This may not be exactly what you need but will be a better starting point.